# Covering of Complete Metric Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Baire's Theorem says that if $X$ is a complete metric space and $$X=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k,$$ then there exists an $n$ s.t. $\stackrel{\circ}{\overline{A_n}}\neq\emptyset$. **However,** is it possible to have $\stackrel{\circ}{A_k}=\emptyset$ for all $k$ ?

Comment: Put $X=\mathbb{R}$, $A_1=\mathbb{Q}$ and $A_2=\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, say on the real line you could take $A_0$ to be the rationals, and 
whatever $A_n$ you were given for $n\ge1$ change them to $A_n'=A_n\setminus A_0$. 
Then none of these sets has non-empty interior.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  You can take $ I\subset\mathbb R $ the irrationals and then $$\mathbb R=\mathbb Q\cup I. $$

Comment: How is $0$ (or any rational) in the union?

Comment: Yes, I forgot about $\mathbb Q$. My bad.